# Javascript show DIV element when seconds goes away and option to hide the bar after that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on one Javascript that is showing content after seconds.

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var count = 5,
    countdown = setInterval(function () {
        $("p.countdown").html(count);
        if (count == 0) {
            $("p.countdown").html("MY TEXT POPUP");
            clearInterval(countdown);
        }
        count--;
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
<p class="countdown"></p>
```

So for now i know how i can display text after seconds gone away but i want to ask how i can show DIV element if this element is hidden?

Here is the `CSS` code of the element that i want to be shown only when seconds are = 0:

```
#countblock{
    display:none;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#F1f1f1;
}
```

So how i can make this block appears instead of the text, and be not viewable before the seconds are = 0.

My other questions is how i can make a div block element with text `"X"` and when you click on this `"X"` to hide the block?

I hope i explained my questions good.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

If you want to show and hide the elements by using their class or id

Ex

```
$('#ID').show() // by id show
$('.countdown').hide() //by class hide
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hide()` and `show()` functions of JQuery :

```
if (count == 0) {
    $("p.countdown").html("MY TEXT POPUP");
    $("p.countdown").show();
    clearInterval(countdown);
}
```

Or `css()` function :

```
$("#countblock").css('display', 'block');
```

For the second question, you can use the function `click()` :

```
<p id="clickToHide"> X </p>

<script>
    $('#clickToHide').click(function() {
        $('.countdown').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but can you please show me in JSFiddle the whole HTML and Javascript code? I can't make this run. I have included Jquery in the head tag..

Comment: Thanks but i have problem only with the "X" hiding block. When i click on X it's not hiding the block like in JSfiddle. Here you can inspect my whole code: http://www.vemvo.com/test/index.html

Comment: I have edited my link.. now it's correct you can check the code.

Comment: Did you try with `css('display', 'none')` ?

Comment: Yes but it's not hiding the block as in JSSFidle. I am using Jquery 1.8.2 `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` Does it matter?

Comment: Can you try not to use the CSS to hide the block initialy ? For example you can use `$('p#countblock').hide();` in the beginning of your JS.

Comment: I have coppied the code from the JSSFidle but when i click on "X" nothing happens. There is my problem. I've also removed the CSS display:none but when i do that the block is show even before the secconds goes away..

Comment: This "X" is not clickable and when i try to click on it it's not hiding the block as in JSSFiddle.

Comment: But you could replace the `#countblock{ display:none; }` in the CSS file by `$('p#countblock').hide();` in the JS. Just to try

Comment: Can you please give me another example in JSFiddle because i can get you right probably. I think i've done this and it's not working as intended

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Pwtnp/1/ 
Otherwise you could update your JQuery.

Comment: I have updated to: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js and it's still not working. Can you check my code here: http://www.vemvo.com/test/index.html ?

Comment: Try stuffs with the functions we gave you. You can use for example `alert('foo');` in you JS code to check if a line is well called. You should find by yourself. I don't know what to do, it works on JSFiddle. Good luck, I saw you have made another question, you can continue there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `display: none` at CSS, you should use:

```
if (count == 0) {
            $("#countblock").css('display','block');
            clearInterval(countdown);
        }
```